# Sending messages from client to server using Spring Websocket STOMP Java

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I was going through the documentation available on Internet regarding sending/receiving messages using Spring Websocket STOMP. I could see various examples of sending messages from Backend to frontend (example given below) but don't see any examples to send the messages from frontend to backend.. Can someone please help?

//controller code
*this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/update/data", message)*

//Frontend code
*stompClient.subscribe('/update/data', function ()...*

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `stomp-js` documentation? There is a `(void) send(destination, headers = {}, body = '')` declaration.

https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/class/Client.html

Answer (score 0):

Following the client-side code snippet, I can guess you are using the [*stompjs*](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs) library for client setup.

Once your `stompClient` setup, the library offers a `send` method that you can use the to send messages for a specific messaging destination using the underlying STOMP-protocol `SEND` frame:

```
stompClient.send('/queue/some-queue', {}, "Some message");
```

The above line will send a STOMP message to the */queue/some-queue* destination with empty (`{}`) headers and a *Some messsage* text.